# Qt5.5 QByteArray indexOf mid wrong result

Tags: substring, indexof, qt5.5, qbytearray

I have an XML file in a QByteArray I am using the indexOf method to find a string in the array, but the position returned isn't correct.  If I examine the data content using qDebug I can see that the data has escape characters which isn't a problem but I don't think indexOf is counting the escape characters.

For example the result from:

```
    qDebug() << arybytXML;
```

A snippet from the result of this is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--\n Node:          gui\n Attrbuttes:    left, right, top and bottom defines the pixel white space to allow\n                from the edge of the display\n\t\tlanguage, should be set to the appropriate country code, an XML file named using\n\t\tthe country code must exist, e.g. 44.xml\n//-->\n<gui id=\"root\" bottom=\"0\" left=\"0\" right=\"0\" top=\"24\" language=\"44\">
```

I use the code:

```
    intOpenComment = arybytXML.indexOf("<!--");
```

The result is that intOpenComment is 39.  If I then search for the end comment and try to extract the data I get the wrong result:

```
    intClosingComment = arybytXML.indexOf("-->", intOpenComment);

    QString strComment = arybytXML.mid(intOpenComment
                                      ,intClosingComment + strlen("-->"));
```

Result:

```
    <!--\n Node:          gui\n Attrbuttes:    left, right, top and bottom defines the pixel white space to allow\n                from the edge of the display\n\t\tlanguage, should be set to the appropriate country code, an XML file named using\n\t\tthe country code must exist, e.g. 44.xml\n//-->\n<gui id=\"root\" bottom=\"0\" left=\"0\" rig"
```

The result should stop after -->, why is there more data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when using mid, the 2nd parameter should be the number of bytes and needed to have 'intOpenComment' removed.